# Exchange Web Services and Property Sets

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I need to retrieve calendar information by invoking the Exchange Web Service in BPOS. I'm using a `CalendarView` with a `PropertySet` to retrieve as little data as possible. However, property sets seems to be limited. I need the `EmailAddress` of the one who made the calendar appointment so I thought I could use the `AppointmentSchema.Organizer` in the `PropertySet`.

When fetching a whole appointment I can get the e-mail through `appt.Organizer.EmailAddress`. But with the code below the `Organizer.EmailAddress` is always null. I've enabled the trace and checked it and only the `Organizer.Name` property is sent, nothing else. Does anyone have a solution on how to get the `EmailAddress` when using a `PropertySet`?

```
CalendarView view = new CalendarView(dtFrom, dtTo);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject);
view.PropertySet.Add(ItemSchema.Id);
view.PropertySet.Add(AppointmentSchema.Start);
view.PropertySet.Add(AppointmentSchema.End);
view.PropertySet.Add(AppointmentSchema.Organizer); // This should contain EmailAddress but it doesn't

Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox("myemail@test.ab");
FolderId id = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, mailbox);
CalendarFolder folder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, id);
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = folder.FindAppointments(view);
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work (does for me):

```
service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new CalendarView(start, end)).Where(s => DateTime.Now < s.Start);
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(appointments, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

Answer (score 1):

As best as I have been able to figure out EWS is a little buggy when it comes to populating the full EmailAddress details both in Appointments for Organizer and for other things like "EmailMessage.From". When you do a query for *multiple* items, you don't get the EmailAddress properties being fully populated. E.g. using APIs like:

```
Folder.FindItems
ExchangeService.FindAppointments
```

I find that *only* the display name in the EmailAddress fields gets populated.

To get the EmailAddress fully populated I find I need to load/bind to the specific item and specify the relevant EmailAddress property, e.g. AppointmentSchema.Organizer in your case. So although you specify exactly the same property to load, you are loading using a single item call rather than a bulk query. E.g. using:

```
ServiceObject.Load
```

Which is available for both Appointment and EmailMessage as they both derive off ServiceObject. Using Item.Bind with the appropriate property set defined should also work.

As an aside I figured this out looking at the code for EwsEditor which is mentioned here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdav_101/archive/2009/11/10/ews-has-more-happy-now-ews-managed-api-and-ewseditor.aspx

The usability of EwsEditor is fairly sucky, and the code takes some trawling to figure out, but at least it does show examples of exercising many of the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

```
service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new CalendarView(start, end)).Where(s => DateTime.Now < s.Start);
service.LoadPropertiesForItems(appointments, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Isn't this just a copy of the answer by @Jordan? If you're trying to say that answer worked for you, you should post that message as a comment on that answer.